# First time trying to use Android and my fileHandler class won't write the email and password to the textfile "app/accounts.txt"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My FileHandler class does not work in my application but works when I try and run it with coverage in another java file.

```java
public class FileHandler {

    public Scanner fileReader;
    public PrintWriter printWriter;

    public void write(String email, String password, boolean tutor) {
        try {
            String filePath = "app/accounts.txt";
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);

            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            String message = email + "," + password + "," + tutor;
            printWriter.println(message);
            printWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
class LoginSignUp : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var logInButton: Button
    lateinit var signUpButton : Button
    lateinit var emailField: EditText
    lateinit var passwordField : EditText
    lateinit var email : String
    lateinit var password : String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.loginsignup)
    
        logInButton = findViewById(R.id.login)
        signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.SignUpButton)
        passwordField = findViewById(R.id.EnterPasswordField)
        emailField = findViewById(R.id.EmailAddressField)
    
        logInButton.setOnClickListener {
            email = emailField.getText().toString()
            password = passwordField.getText().toString()
    
            val fileHandler = FileHandler()
            if (email == "tutor@email.com" && password == "tutor123") {
                //Line of Issue
                fileHandler.write(email, password, true)
                // -----------
                setContentView(R.layout.tutormenu)
            } else if (email == "student@email.com" && password == "student123")
                setContentView(R.layout.studentmenu)
        }
    
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            email = emailField.text.toString()
            password = passwordField.text.toString()
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that the loginButton handler works how it is supposed to and have been able to isolate the issue of my code to the fileHandler implementation. Now, I'm not sure how to go about  execution of the fileHandler wherein if the email and password match the specified text they will be written to a file. I thought writing this line of code in my manifest would resolve it but it didn't.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. My email and password still won't write to the textfile

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't have caused the problem anyway (I was wrong to suggest that as the cause, so I deleted my comment and retracted my close vote).

Comment: Maybe you should check if an exception was thrown. You catch the exception and print the exception message to standard error. Where is that appearing if you're running on Android? It's usually a bad idea, in most cases, to have an exception handler that just prints a stack trace. Just remove the catch, and let your exception propagate to its callers. You'll probably see an error message more easily like that.

Comment: I tried that but now my application stops responding. Furthermore, it does not print an error message. I'm unsure how to navigate android studio and determine where the error occurs and how to go about resolving it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using "equals()" function instead of "==" to compare the content of two String.

Do this:

```
if (email.equals("tutor@email.com") && password.equals("tutor123")) {
            //Line of Issue
            fileHandler.write(email, password, true)
            // -----------
            setContentView(R.layout.tutormenu)
        } else if (email.equals("student@email.com") && password.equals("student123"))
            setContentView(R.layout.studentmenu)
    }
```

The main difference is that, equals checks the content of two Strings if they have the same contents. But == checks the location of two Strings in memory.

Comment: This is true only for Java, but the OP's code is in Kotlin and `==` works fine.

Comment: @k314159 Yes, my bad, I saw the Java code snippet first and didn't notice that the second code snippet was written in Java or Kotlin. sorry.

Comment: Understood, no worries